# Displaying check mark when user selected a tableview row in swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to display check mark only at selected row as shown in below screenshot. 
[image]

Here delete and check mark are dynamically created button.

Here my tableview methods below.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if list.count == 0 {
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "No layout found. Please add at least one plist file with correct format.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    return list.count
}
var btn = UIButton()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    if let cell = cell {
        print("cell is available")
        // Remove previously created button from reused cell view
        if let button = cell.contentView.subviews.first(where: { (view: UIView) -> Bool in
            view.isKind(of: UIButton.self)
        }) {
            button.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    } else {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left

    cell?.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.row == (list.count - 1) {
        cell?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    } else {
        btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom) as UIButton
        btn.frame = CGRect(x: 146, y: 0, width: 20, height: (cell?.frame.height)!)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.tag = indexPath.row
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "delete.png"), for: .normal)
        cell?.contentView.addSubview(btn)
    }
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if list[indexPath.row] == "➕ Add Room"{
        print("ADd reoom selrctj")
        self.delegate?.enterRoomName()

    }else{
        self.delegate?.slecetedPicklist(fileName: list[indexPath.row])
        self.removeFromSuperview() //hiding drop down

        if indexPath.row == btn.tag{ //Here it's not correct i think
            btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "check_mark.png"), for: .normal)
        }else{
            btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "delete.png"), for: .normal)
        }
        self.table?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Afetr this implementation i'm not able to achieve this requirement and result is shown below. Even after selecting row it shows delete and this drop down when tap on it i'm removing it from superview.

[image]

Can somebody please suggest me how to implement this or where i'm doing wrong?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are not reloading your tablview in didselect.

Comment: Even better if you use one button & toggle them with 2 states selected/default.

Comment: Rather than using a generic `UITableViewCell` I would suggest that you create your own `UITableViewCell` subclass.  You can then add the button in that class and expose it via a property.  That will eliminate the need to search the view hierarchy or use tags to try and identify the button.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Thanks for your response, i tried reloading tableview and assgined two images(delete and checkmark for default and selected ) and making btn.isSelected == true/false and it's not workring. Can you plz suggest other approach.

Comment: @MIOSY If you do not wanted to take unnecessary headache then follow as Paul said. Here is [tutorial](http://kylegoslan.co.uk/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-xib-swift/) create cell through XIB first and add your button there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store (add/remove item or index as per item select and deselect) item or item index in the array and update(Reload) selected row in `didSelectRowAt` method use following code.

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: false)
```

And then you need to check in `cellForRowAt` method if item available in the array then display tick mark accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not able to implement as you said plz elaborate more regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the button, use the same button with different icons for selected/normal state. It will show the required icon on same button
Once you select a button, change the selection state of button & reload the table or reload that particular row. The changes will reflect.